# if(double type == char type)

Tags: c++, if-statement, conditional-statements, c++14, c++17

**Trying to condition a double type with a char type. But there seems to be no output.**

Here's an example:

```
double x;
cin >> x;

if(x == 'a') cout << "ye";
```

*edit1: sorry for not being specific*

**Main Goal:**

1.) I'm currently trying to build a calculator in which, that if you input a char into a variable(which is supposed to be a double or int maybe), the expected output will be printed, even under the condition of data type errors.

2.) This calculator is like an algebra calculator(but it isn't what you would expect from the foundations of deriving formulas), I'm not a yet experienced when it comes to these kinds of complex inputs, outputs, and algorithms.

3.) From the point of number 1, I do not know what solutions can I get when conditioning data types.

Comment: _But there seems to be no output...._ What output are you expecting?

Comment: Why did you expect any output? Why would a `double` value, inputted as a floating point number, be equal to a character? What are you really trying to accomplish? What is the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: What is your input? 97 (value in ascii for `'a'`)?

Comment: Work as expected [here](https://ideone.com/G3Sbi2).

Comment: "if you input a char into a variable(which is supposed to be a double or int maybe), the expected output will be printed". What do you mean? If I want to add two numbers in your calculator and by mistake I input `2.4 + a` what would be the expected output?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not how input works. If you use `>>` to get into into a `double` variable, the function handling the input will fail if there's some input that doesn't match that of a `double` value. If you need mixed input then you better read full lines and do the parsing into numbers and "variables" yourself.

Comment: oh, I tried several times with the condition changed into `x==97`, changed x into int, _(the only expected output came when I inputed 97, and changed x into int)_ @Jarod42

Comment: ahhhhhh okok, _sorry for the late replies, i'm new at this stackoverflow sorry ehhe_

is there any solution that I can do, to make anything I input as a character on stdin, instead of not entering an ascii, to make take the output as expected based on the work of @Jarod42, and the other errors stated by the others?

Comment: an error @bolov

Comment: @jejemojaja then where does it come into play `if(x == 'a')` ?

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh omg, sorry so much, thank you mr@Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @bolov, it comes into play when I'm about to enter 'a' into the stdin. Then the whole formula will solve the other variables _(not stated on the code given above)_ without the variable x(doubleType). It serves a function when to know that the other given variables _(not stated on the code above)_ needs an input of the x, to find the value of x. But now I'll try to do what you guys suggested. Thank you btw

Answer (score 3):

Because of the condition, there is output only when `x` is equal to `'a'`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem this code is trying to solve is that the **text** that's typed in is supposed to be interpreted as **either** a numeric value **or** a character. Reading it into a numeric type won't (easily) support this. So read it into a type that holds **text** and examine the text to decide what to do next:

```
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;
if (std::isdigit(input[0])
    std::cout << std::stod(input) << '\n'; // got a number; convert it and write it out
else
    std::cout << input[0] << '\n'; // got some other character; write it out
```